# sort on two variables using ggplot and reorder

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know the following works:

`p = ggplot(df_full_short,aes(x=reorder(unit,(var1)), y=dev)) + …`

but I need to sort my graph on two variables, not one.  So something like this:

`p = ggplot(df_full_short,aes(x=reorder(unit,(var1,**var2**)), y=dev)) + …`

except this doesn't work.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
ggplot(df_full_short,aes(x=reorder(unit, paste(var1, var2)), y=dev)) + 
      ...
```

---

Or may be change the `unit` `levels` based on the 'var1', 'var2'

```
library(dplyr)
df_full_short %>%
         arrange(var1, var2) %>%
         mutate(unit = factor(unit, levels = unique(unit))) %>%
          ggplot(aes(x = unit, y = dev)) + 
           ...
```

Comment: what is the rationale of using paste? it doesn't make sense to me off the top of my head

Comment: @DerekKrantz  I didn't test it.  But, I assume may be either the `paste` or the recently updated may be what you are looking for

Comment: ```paste``` doesn't seem to work actually.  nothing seems to be sorted, although I don't get an error

Comment: @DerekKrantz what about the second option.  The `unit` is now sorted based on the 'var1', 'var2'